# How do I install glass mosaic tile around an outside rounded corner?

Tags: tile

I'm installing a glass tile mosaic backsplash in my kitchen. I've got an outside rounded corner that I want to install the tile around. The diameter of the rounded corner is approximately 1". What is the best way to install the tile? Are there corner pieces that I should use (I didn't see anything at Lowe's)? Or do you just cut the tiles to wrap around? Seems that would look odd unless done really well (first time tiling, so not an expert).

Comment: You can't tile that corner in the manner you are thinking without a "corner bead" tile of the same type. You will either have to square off the corner and tile it with your mosaic tile, or find a "corner-bead" tile that complements your overall design and incorporate into your job. I guess your could try to slice thin strips of the mosaic and adhere it across the radius but that seems iffy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to tile the corner, however, if I did tile the corner, I think I would use position the tile vertically around the corner. I am planning on laying the tile horizontally for the walls and use some of the tile laid vertically for the edges. The corner would then compliment the edges. The only drawback I see to this is that the grout lines will be wider around the corner. Though I could probably solve that by removing the tile from the backing and placing them closer together around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this:

- Buy a glass rounded piece that will fit (very hard to find but your specialty shops will have them or can order them)
- just like an artist would do, break the glass into small enough pieces that you can make a rounded joint out of them.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a stainless steel corner bead for tiles from lowe's which will hide the cuts and compliment the stainless appliances.